# Tiny, cheap audio buffer with mute?

Tags: audio, operational-amplifier, buffer

I need to buffer an audio signal (feeding into a variable input impedance), and make it mutable with a digital control.  The best thing I can think of is an op-amp (maybe [TS971](http://www.st.com/stonline/products/literature/ds/6031/ts971.htm)? 3×2 mm SOT23) feeding into an analog switch, like [NLAS4599](http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=NLAS4599) (3×3 mm TSOP-6), but this requires several external components ([example circuits](http://www.geofex.com/article_folders/cd4053/cd4053.htm)).

Anyone know of anything better?  A tiny IC that acts as both a unity-gain buffer and a digitally-controlled mute?  Supplies are 4.5 V and ground, signal is biased to half that, and the mute and unmute transitions should be pop-free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would any old op-amp/buffer with a shutdown signal be sufficient? Digikey has TONS of options if this is acceptable. <s>MAX9812 is a SC70-6 package, for example.</s> (Not a buffer.  [LMV341](http://www.national.com/pf/LM/LMV341.html) is a single op-amp with shutdown in an SC70-6 package.)

Comment: That's a fixed-gain 20 dB mic amp, not a unity-gain buffer, but yes, something like that with an internal switch might work.

Comment: LMV341 looks promising, with a high output impedance in shutdown so that the DC bias will remain unchanged until you turn it back on, assuming it's only connected to a capacitor.

Comment: op amp with shutdown.

Comment: @endolith, better yet, a resistor from output to the "zero" level will ensure that the signal goes to zero.

Comment: @markrages: Agreed.  Something like this: http://tinyurl.com/26nb4j2

Answer (score 7):

If you really want zero clicks, then you want to fade to zero instead of shutting off suddenly, because that is still introducing a step change to the signal.  Or maybe you could shut off on a zero crossing, but I can't think of an obvious circuit to do so.

I think I would feed the signal into a divider made of a resistor and FET to ground, and put an RC on the gate of the FET so it would switch slowly into conduction.  This will introduce a severe DC bias in the output, so it could be capacitively coupled into the opamp.  If the DC bias is applied and removed slowly, it won't cause a pop.  Remind me and I will sketch the circuit up.

Comment: http://neatcircuits.com/audiosw/index.html has a schematic using a JFET for fading in and out as a mute

Comment: Nice, those circuits are a lot easier to read than my description.